# <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

This is the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.web.controllers" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<!--  <mvc:default-servlet-handler />  -->

  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </beans:bean>    

</beans:beans>



    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>mypage</title>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/resources/mycustom/fabrication.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/resources/mycustom/boxmodel.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/resources/css/moslake_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/resources/css/boxmodel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/resources/css/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/resources/css/media.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#F5FAFA">
    <h1>${pageContext.request.contextPath}</h1>
    <div class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5"></div><!--end of first row columns-->
          <div class="col-md-2">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/swing.png" alt="swing logo" height="50" width="100"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5"></div>
         </div><!--end of row-->
         
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-5">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
               <li>
                <button  class="dropdown-toggle btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown"  type="button">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><p align="center">Projects List</p></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#"><b>Project1</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><b>Project2</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><b>Project3</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><b>Project4</b></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><b>Project5</b></a></li>
                </ul>
               </li>
               <li  class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><p align="center">Add</p></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#"><b>New Project</b></a></li>
            </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                <form class="navbar-search" id="srch" action="#">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
               </li>
               <li>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</button>
            </form>
               </li>
              </ul> 
             </div><!--end of col-md-5-->
                        
               <div class="col-md-4"></div><!--end of col-md-4-->
               
               <div class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                 <li>
                  <a class="btn btn-basic">hello!
                   <span class="badge">Abbas Kapasi</span>
                  </a>
                 </li>
                 <li  class="dropdown">
                  <button class="dropdown-toggle btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li> 
            </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>
               </div><!--end of col-md-3-->
              
          </div><!--end of nested row-->
        </div><!--end of main container-->     
    </div><!--end of nav-->
    </div><!--end of header-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

This causes following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/containers/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18437394/815227). Anyways, there are many duplicates of this question and all related to problems in either (or both) the classpath or/and Maven/Gradle configuration.

Comment: thnks.. i already gone through suggested ans but it couldn't help me out..

Comment: when i remove <mvc:resources mapping=“/resources/**” location=“/resources/” />  from the dispatcher-servlet.xml it's working fine , but it does not load my css and js files.

Comment: Is */resources* located in the right place? I mean, it's has to be in the same level as WEB-INF, not under it.
For instance: */webapp/resoucres*, */webapp/WEB-INF*.

Comment: yes,it is in the right palce! i am using eclipse juno under ubuntu 14, so the directory hierarchy is like projectName/WebContent/resources..                 it is at same level as WEB-INF folder